# Reverse Image Search API in Android

Tags: android

I am working on an android application where app user takes a picture and post it. I wonder how could I get the name of the taken image from reverse image google search? Is there a public api?

For example when a user takes a picture of his car, then description of the taken picture automatically fills with "car".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's no reverse image search API from Google out of the box.
People just build systems which mimic `image search behaviour` via doing the requests to Google servers theirselves.

The easiest way for this is the following process:

1. Build your own backend, where you'll upload photos which have public-facing URL.
2. Perform a request to `https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=<URL>`, parse the response, execute some returned JavaScript and grab the metadata.
3. Return the data to your app in the required format.

This is not documented anywhere. So it can change anytime in the future.

Google has specific `Custom Search API`, but as of now, it doesn't support reverse image search.